# List all the tables and row counts in Teradata SQL?

Tags: teradatasql

I would like to translate the following Oracle SQL query into Teradata SQL:

```
SELECT table_name, num_rows FROM ALL_TABLES
```

This query retrieves all the tables along with the number of rows. What is the Teradata SQL equivalent?

Comment: You can retrieve `TableName` from `dbc.TablesV` view; you likely will want to qualify by "schema" which is referred to as `DatabaseName` in Teradata. The actual number of rows is not directly available without SELECT COUNT(*) from each table. You can potentially retrieve a `RowCount` as of the last statistics collection from `dbc.StatsV where StatsID=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and play :)

SELECT  DatabaseName,
TableName,
CreateTimeStamp,
LastAlterTimeStamp
FROM    DBC.TablesV